# How to set two register values equal to each other in assembly language?

Tags: variables, assembly

new to assembly language here. Let's say I want to do B=3, and if I want to set A=B, how should I do it if register 0 is B and register 1 is A?

Usually we do initialization of variables with const instruction but it only takes in immediate values instead of a register value.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You haven't even specified which instruction set architecture or assembler you're talking about.

Comment: What architecture and assembler are you programming for?

Answer (score 1):

Most ISAs have a `mov` or `move` instruction (which is actually a register copy, not destroying the source).  But `mov` is the traditional name<sup>1</sup>.  ["mov" of "assembly language" meant copy or move?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57916302/mov-of-assembly-language-meant-copy-or-move)

Some ISAs like MIPS have a zero register or otherwise don't need a separate machine opcode for `move`.  e.g. `move $t1, $t2` = `ori $t1, $t2, 0` is one way to implement it, or `addu` with `$zero`, or many other ways an assembler can choose from.  In that case, `move` is usually supported as a pseudo-instruction in the asm source.

Footnote 1: "copy" might have gotten a mnemonic like `cpy` which might be ambiguous with "compare", especially on an old 8-bit microcontroller where `cpy` might mean "compare with the contents of the Y register".